# Removing Border/Margin/Padding from Form

Tags: codenameone

I created a derived `Form` class, with the constructor using `GridLayout` as a parameter.

How do I remove the white border(or the margin/padding) from a form object? I tried updating `listItemGapInt` in my `theme.res` but that failed to work.

Here is an example of a form taking up the screen. (I believe the border is coming from my `Form`, it may be from my `GridLayout`)

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override both `Form` and `ContentPane` UIID's in the theme and make sure they have 0 padding/margin:

1. Double click theme.res
2. Select "Theme"
3. Click Add on the bottom
4. Type in `Form` on the top combo box
5. Select Margin tab and uncheck the Derive flag. Do the same for padding
6. Repeat this with `ContentPane` instead of form
7. Press Save in the designer tool